# Parsing on a date not working

Tags: java, date, parsing, datetime

I'm running in a problem when i'm trying to convert a String to a java.util.Date.

My date is formatted like that : **Jan 23 2016 4:00:24 PM** and I want to convert that String to a Date object. So to do that i'm using a **SimpleDateFormat** with the parameters that seems good to me according to the javadoc : **MMM dd yyyy  aa.**

But when i'm running my code i'm encountering a java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Jan 23 2016 4:00:24 PM"

What could be my problem ?

Thanks !

EDIT : the code in question

```
String dateStr = "Jan 23 2016 4:00:24 PM";
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
Date date = parserSDF.parse(dateStr);
```

Comment: The `MMM` pattern is locale-dependent. You could try specifying the locale explicitly: `SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss aa", Locale.US);`

Comment: Yep adding the locale.US did the trick, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your default system locale? You can check it with `Locale.getDefault()` method call. I've tried your code, works fine for me with default `en_US` locale. But I tried to use another one (I used Chinese) and caught the same error.

Try to use `SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss aa", Locale.US);` with explicitly defined locale

Answer (score 1):

This code runs fine for me, and produces the output **Sat Jan 23 16:00:24 EST 2016**

```
    String text = "Jan 23 2016 4:00:24 PM";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss aa", Locale.US);
    try {
        System.out.println(sdf.parse(text));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Well that's pretty strange, your code still raise an exception on my computer.... Could it be because of the JDK i'm using ? (1.8u60)

Comment: That is weird. I can run fine that program with Java 8. Try using this site: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php